# Invariance of the domain of self-adjoint operator by nonlinear map.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $N: D(N)\subset H \to H$ be some  self-adjoint operator with domain $D(N)$ dense in $H$ and spectrum 
$$\sigma(N) \subset (-\infty, \alpha]$$
for some fixed $\alpha <0.$ We assume further that 
$$e^{tN}(D(N))\subset D(N), \quad \forall t\in (0, 1].$$ 
Let now $g: H \to H$ such that $g(D(N)) \subset D(N)$ and  there exist $C,s>0$ 
$$\|g(u)\| \leq C\|u\|^s\, \forall u \in H. $$
Define 
$$\psi(u):= \int_0^\infty e^{tN}g(tu)\, dt.$$

1. Can we  prove that $\psi (D(N))\subset D(N)$  and that 
   $$N\psi(u)= \int_0^\infty N e^{tN}g(tu)\, dt ?$$
2. If the answer on the above question is yes, can this result be generalised by taking $N$ to be normal with spectrum 
   $$\sigma(N) \subset \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: {\rm Re}(\lambda) \leq \alpha\}?$$
   The assumption on $e^{tN}$ on the interval $(0,1]$ implies that 
   $$e^{tN}(D(N))\subset D(N), \quad \forall t\in (0, \infty).$$
   Then I don't know if it makes sense to write 
   $$\psi(u) = \sum_{n =O}^{\infty}\int_{n}^{n+1} e^{tN}g(tu)\, dt$$

Thank you for any hint.